# Is there a way to combine duplicate environment variables for different deployment environments on vercel?

Tags: environment-variables, vercel

I am using the same key names for both the preview and production deployments on vercel. I want to know if there's a way to combine the duplicates but set them differently for each environment.

[image]

I have looked at the vercel docs, and searched on google but I don't see any solutions.